# What is the name of this card game?

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm looking for the name of this game in English.

It's a drinking game, in which the participants get together in a circle and, with a playing cards deck, draw cards and follow their drinking rules (according to each card value).

E.g.: I drew a Queen, so all the ladies that are playing must drink. My friend then draws a Two, so he chooses 2 people to drink. Etc.

Does anyone know this game?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's one variation](http://fundrinkinggames.net/kings-cup-rules/), having a couple different names:

> Kings Cup (AKA Ring Of Fire or Circle Of Death) Is a popular card drinking game. To play the game you should have a medium size group (at least 4 players). You start by placing a red cup in the middle of everyone and spread a deck of cards around it face down. You then go around in a circle taking turns drawing cards following the rules below.
>   The Objective?: Draw all of the Kings

I'm guessing there are many variations of this game, going by many names.